# How do I edit the GoodRx widget to show multiple drugs?

Tags: javascript, php, wordpress, widget

I am trying to edit the following code for placement on my WordPress site, but I can not seem to figure out how to either:

1. add multiple drugs to the same widget
2. show the widget separately for 3 different drugs

I would prefer to do (1) but if it not possible I would like to display three widgets.

Here is the script from http://www.goodrx.com/developer/widget:

```
<div id="goodrx_compare-price_widget"> </div>
<script>
   var _grxdn = "axelex";
 (function(d,t){var g=d.createElement(t),s=d.getElementsByTagName(t)[0];
 g.src="//s3.amazonaws.com/assets.goodrx.com/static/widgets/compare.min.js";
 s.parentNode.insertBefore(g,s)}(document,"script"));
</script>
```

Comment: bahahah yes this is the support department for every third party script ever written

Answer (score 0):

I dont think you can add multiple drugs to the same widget as the API format supports only one drug per widget. You can however, display three different widgets like this :

```
<script>
   var _grxdn = "drug_name_1";
 (function(d,t){var g=d.createElement(t),s=d.getElementsByTagName(t)[0];
 g.src="//s3.amazonaws.com/assets.goodrx.com/static/widgets/compare.min.js";
 s.parentNode.insertBefore(g,s)}(document,"script"));
</script>

var _grxdn = "drug_name_2";
 (function(d,t){var g=d.createElement(t),s=d.getElementsByTagName(t)[0];
 g.src="//s3.amazonaws.com/assets.goodrx.com/static/widgets/compare.min.js";
 s.parentNode.insertBefore(g,s)}(document,"script"));
</script>

var _grxdn = "drug_name_3";
 (function(d,t){var g=d.createElement(t),s=d.getElementsByTagName(t)[0];
 g.src="//s3.amazonaws.com/assets.goodrx.com/static/widgets/compare.min.js";
 s.parentNode.insertBefore(g,s)}(document,"script"));
</script>
```

The format of the widget should be like this:

```
URL Parameters  
api_key
Required
name
Required if ndc excluded
Expected Data Type: String
Example: “lipitor”
```

More:

> http://www.goodrx.com/developer/documentation#fp-format

Comment: Widgets don't require an API key